# Rails api - why incorrect ID send null instead of 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-api

When I enter an incorrect track_id in url for example : `tracks/123456`

=> it returns `404 not found` as expected !

If I try with  incorrect `challenge_id` which is one of my other model :  `tracks/1/challenges/12345`

=> it return `null` instead of `404 not found`.

The code of both seems to be the same so I can't found the issue.

If you could help me to found why I get `null` instead of `404`, seeing the code below :

**routes.rb**

```html
 resources :tracks do
   resources :challenges do
    resources :ressources
   end 
 end
```

**challenges_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    render json: @challenge, include: [:ressources, :challenges_startups]
  end

  private

  def set_challenge
     @track = Track.find(params[:track_id])
     @challenge = @track.challenges.where(id: params[:id]).first
   end
```

**tracks_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    render json: @track, include: [:challenges]
  end

 private

 def set_track
    @track = Track.find(params[:id])
 end
```

**rails_server**

*For challenges => the wrong one*

```
Started GET "/tracks/3/challenges/20/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 12:24:19 +0200
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ChallengesController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"track_id"=>"3", "id"=>"20"}
  Track Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE "tracks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Challenge Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "challenges".* FROM "challenges" WHERE "challenges"."track_id" = ? AND "challenges"."id" = ? ORDER BY "challenges"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["track_id", 3], ["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Startup Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "startups".* FROM "startups" ORDER BY "startups"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Class (0.18ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 19.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

*For tracks*

```
Started GET "/tracks/222" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 12:30:37 +0200
Processing by TracksController#show as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"222"}
  Track Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE "tracks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 222], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Startup Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "startups".* FROM "startups" ORDER BY "startups"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.16ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (Views: 4.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: What's your code for instantiating `@challenge` and `@track`? My guess is that `@track` is using `find` which throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

Comment: I updated my question with corresponding code! Indeed `@track` is using `find` whereas `@challenge`is using `where`. So this is the issue thank you. But I don't know who to edit my method to use `find` instead of `where`  do you have an idea ?

Comment: I think you can do next: `@challenge = @track.challenges.find(params[:id])

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `@challenge` like below

```
@challenge = @track.challenges.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

`where` returns `nil` if there is *no record matching the condition*. That is why you get *null* instead of *404 not found*.

Whereas `find` in contrast returns *404 not found* if the record doesn't exist.

If you want to get *404 not found*, then modify `@challenge` like below

```
@challenge = @track.challenges.find(params[:id])
```